# how to implement mediaplayer autoplay feature in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, mp3, media-player, android-recyclerview

I have multiple songs in recyclerview. I have to implement autoplay feature like normal media player when one song completes the next must play on next position in recyclerview.

Thanks for any help.

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                focusedItem = getLayoutPosition();
                Log.d("TAG_LIST", "Element " + focusedItem + " clicked.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you should use MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener and play song on next position

Comment: @Alexander i am doing the same but the next songs are playing only on the first position.

Comment: looks like its issue with get next position item, may be this link will be useful
http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/

Comment: @Alexander i am not getting how to implement it in the MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.

Comment: save position in implemented onItemClicked listener, and use it in MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, not gracefully but i think it will be work

Comment: @Alexander i have tried to get the position using above method.

Comment: and i returns first position?

Comment: @Alexander is any other way to do this..